# Why pointer return 0 in foor loop

Tags: c++, pointers, for-loop

I have the following function:

```
void printKMax(int arr[], int n, int k){
    int* start = &arr[0];
    int* run = new int();
    if(n > 1){
        int* run = &arr[1];
        cout << "Initial run pointer " << *run << endl;
    }else {
        cout << *start << endl;
        return;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < k-1; i++){
        cout << "Run in for loop " << *run << endl;
    }   
    delete run;
}
```

Input `arr = {3 4 6 3 4}` and `k = 4`. 
First cout prints `4`, while for loop cout prints `0` three times. Why does it give `0` and not `4`? Why is dereferencing the pointer in for loop different than in if statement?

Comment: You seem to have quite a few misunderstandings about C++. You should take a step back and systematically learn the language from a  good book.

Comment: You have two variables named `run`, one of which shadows the other.

Comment: You never modify the *top-level* `run` variable. It never changes what it points to, which is a zero-initialized `int`.

Comment: *And* you never modify `run` inside the loop. So you will loop `k-1` times printing the exactly same value. Over and over. This is the reason you need to learn how to use a debugger, so you can find such silly problems yourself. Being able to use a debugger is a crucial skill for *all* programmers.

Comment: Modifying the outer `run` to point into the array will invoke UB with `delete run`.  I think @BaummitAugen has the most relevant comment here, and this question should not have been answered.

Comment: @BaummitAugen thank you for the feedback. Could you maybe point out to some of those misunderstandings?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't do that adequately within those comment character limits. I can just stress again how important it is to get and read a good C++ book, the language is too weird to learn it by trial and error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this declaration

```
int* run = new int();
```

there is declared pointer `run` that points to the dynamically allocated memory initialized by zero.

It is the variable that is used in the loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < k-1; i++){
    cout << "Run in for loop " << *run << endl;
}
```

Another pointer with the same name declared in the if statement

```
if(n > 1){
    int* run = &arr[1];
```

is not alive outside the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You declare int* run twice, fill the second and display the first.

Answer (score 0):

You have two different variables! One is defined in the block of the function and initialized to address containing 0, the other defined in the *then* block of the if and initiliazed to address containing 4.

You may read about variable declaration/definition and scope of identifiers.